# How do I get a multi line tooltip in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Right now, I have a tool tip that pops up when I hover over an edit box.  The problem is that this tool tip contains multiple error messages and they are all in one long line.  I need to have each error message be on its own line.  The error messages are contained in a CString with a new line seperating them.

My existing code is below.

```
BOOL OnToolTipText(UINT, NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    ASSERT(pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA || pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTW);
    // need to handle both ANSI and UNICODE versions of the message
    TOOLTIPTEXTA* pTTTA = (TOOLTIPTEXTA*)pNMHDR;
    TOOLTIPTEXTW* pTTTW = (TOOLTIPTEXTW*)pNMHDR;
    //    TCHAR szFullText[256];
    CString strTipText=_T("");
    UINT nID = pNMHDR->idFrom;
    if (pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA && (pTTTA->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND) ||
        pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTW && (pTTTW->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND))
    {
        // idFrom is actually the HWND of the tool
        nID = ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)nID);
    }

    //m_errProjAccel[ch] contains 1 or more error messages each seperated by a new line.
    if((int)nID >= ID_PROJECTED_ACCEL1 && (int)nID < ID_PROJECTED_ACCEL1 + PROJECTED_ROWS -1 ) {
        int ch = nID - ID_PROJECTED_ACCEL1;
        strTipText = m_errProjAccel[ch];
    } 


#ifndef _UNICODE
    if (pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA)
        lstrcpyn(pTTTA->szText, strTipText, sizeof(pTTTA->szText)/sizeof(pTTTA->szText[0]));
    else
        _mbstowcsz(pTTTW->szText, strTipText, sizeof(pTTTA->szText)/sizeof(pTTTA->szText[0]));
#else
    if (pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA)
        _wcstombsz(pTTTA->szText, strTipText, sizeof(pTTTA->szText)/sizeof(pTTTA->szText[0]));
    else
        lstrcpyn(pTTTW->szText, strTipText, sizeof(pTTTA->szText)/sizeof(pTTTA->szText[0]));
#endif
    *pResult = 0;

    // bring the tooltip window above other popup windows
    ::SetWindowPos(pNMHDR->hwndFrom, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);

    return TRUE;    // message was handled
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creating multiline tooltips is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760252.aspx) in the MSDN library - read the "Implementing Multiline ToolTips" section. You should send a `TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH` message to the ToolTip control in response to a `TTN_GETDISPINFO` notification to force it to use multiple lines. In your string you should separate lines with `\r\n`.

Also, if your text is more than 80 characters, you should use the `lpszText` member of the `NMTTDISPINFO` structure instead of copying into the `szText` array.

Comment: I was using \n.  I changed it to \r\n but it does not appear to have helped.

Comment: I found that tooltips accept \n, \r\n, and \r as valid line breaks. I've even been able to mix them in the same tooltip. This is due to bugs/inconsistencies in the software that we'll fix, but it works.

Comment: To use the lpszText you could do like this: ```pTTT->lpszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(strTipText));```