# MFC CMenu tooltip not being displayed

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, tooltip, cmenu

I tried using something like this to set the tool tip of a CMenu item (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400180/mfc-how-to-add-tooltip-in-cmenu-items)) but it is just being displayed in a single line and the line break is not visible.

```
// read control id
UINT id = menu->GetMenuItemID(1235);
// modify caption and add tooltip?
menu->ModifyMenu( id, MF_BYCOMMAND, id, "Click here\nThis is the tooltip for the menu item ...");
```

I also tried to set the caption directly in the visual studio resource designer of the menu item with the same effect.
Can you give me any hints on whats wrong? I am using VS2008 on windows 7.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Trying setting the text in the menu properties, in the Visual Studio designer. I'm not 100% clear on the full context but it seems like this might be an MFC issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `MF_STRING` bit too? E.g. `menu->ModifyMenu( id, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING, id, "Click here\nThis is the tooltip for the menu item ...");`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @JonathanWood : I already tried that (see my original post) and it had the same effect. @JonasGulle : The MF_STRING bit also did not have any effect.

Comment: I assume \r\n might do it. MFC is alway \r\n

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have not added the windows xp common controls to your application.

Try adding the common controls to your stdafx.h:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like an duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153134/how-do-i-get-a-mutli-line-tooltip-in-mfc)

Mainly you should use \r\n instead of \n because this is what mfc expects.

Comment: Does not work. The result is the same as if `\n` alone is used. The text displays in one line and ignores the newline character(s) completely. (Note that the `\r\n` are still in the text as fetching with [`GetMenuString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does copy both characters in the string)